# Настройка vagrant\apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vagrant

Поднял Vagrant с Apache и PHP. Конфиг делал через сайт puphpet.com. Залил проект, но есть проблемы с доступом к файлам из папки files.
Часть структуры папок:

```
site/.code - .php
site/files - файлы
```

Также имеется файл site/files/.htaccess :

```
php_value engine off
```

Если попробовать открыть через браузер любой файл из папки files или files/dir/dir , то вернется 500 ошибка, но если .htaccess удалить, то файлы грузятся.
До этого сидел на OpenServer там таких проблем не было.
Конфиг apache c virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
      Require all granted
      SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
    </FilesMatch>

  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_access.log" combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

$ apachectl -M
Loaded Modules:

```
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgid_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 mpm_worker_module (shared)
```

Comment: смотрите, что появляется в файле `/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_error.log` при 500-м ответе.

Comment: в error.log: `/files/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: *module not included in the server configuration* — вероятно, в этом и причина.

Comment: А какого конкретно модуля не хватает?

Comment: вероятно, модуля *php*.

Comment: Но если не хватает модуля php, то каким образом скрипты .php работают?

Comment: исходя из того, что вы решили пойти нестандартным путём, установив все нужные пакеты из репозитория дистрибутива, могу выдвинуть гипотезу: у вас установлено более одного сервера `apache` в разных местах. и в одних из случаев вы обращаетесь к одной из этих установок, а в других случаях — к другой.

Comment: Очень интересная гипотеза, но может поделитесь способом подтвердить ее или опровергнуть?

Comment: вопрос, конечно, интересный. я бы начал с выяснения того, откуда запускается программа `apachectl` и, далее, как она в этом месте оказалась: принадлежит ли она установленному в системе пакету, либо была скопирована туда «руками» (вариант: каким-нибудь `install.sh`, откуда-то скачанным).

Comment: я нашел ответ, который гораздо больше похож на правду. `The script you are using assumes that PHP is installed as a module. PHP is installed as a CGI on our servers. Your script should have documentation for how to install it on servers that run PHP as a CGI.`

Comment: Осталось выяснить как заставить PHP работать как Apache-модуль, а не как CGI.

Comment: я бы рекомендовал пользоваться собранными для дистрибутива и лежащими в репозитории пакетами. по-моему, это надёжнее и проще.

Comment: Спешу поделиться "Хэппи эндом". Помучив еще немного апач, было принято решение собрать конфиг с nginx. Файлы .htaccess теперь идут лесом. Бонусом стала более шустрая работа связки nginx + php-fpm. Спасибо, что пытались помочь!

Comment: если вы «пошли другим путём», удалите, пожалуйста, этот вопрос: право сделать это есть только у вас и у модераторов.

Answer (score 1):

Смотри что я сделал
1) поставил sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 
если он уже установлен, тогда сначала удали его sudo apt autoremove libapache2-mod-php5, потом установи еще раз.

2) перезапусти apache командой sudo systemctl restart apache2
Он должен выдать ошибку "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

3) зайди в папку /etc/apache/mods-enabled и удали два файла @mpm_worker.conf и @mpm_worker.load 
4) перезапусти apache еще раз sudo systemctl restart apache2
В списке модулей у тебя должна появтся новая строчка в списке подключенных модулей

core_module (static)
so_module (static)
watchdog_module (static)
http_module (static)
log_config_module (static)
logio_module (static)
version_module (static)
unixd_module (static)
access_compat_module (shared)
actions_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authn_core_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
cgid_module (shared)
dav_module (shared)
dav_fs_module (shared)
deflate_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
filter_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
**mpm_prefork_module (shared)**
negotiation_module (shared)
php7_module (shared)
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
reqtimeout_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
socache_shmcb_module (shared)
ssl_module (shared)

Под название mpm_prefork_module и исчезнуть mpm_worker_module (shared)

Это проблем с многопоточностью и совместимотью  модулей mpm_worker и mpm_prefork